# Intent for taking more than one photo

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, photo

A intent for taking photos is quite easy:

```
Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
    takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1)
    }
}
```

Instead of this I would like to create an intent for taking multiple photos just like when you open the photo-app - you can take e.g. 5 photos which are saved in a folder and when all photos are taken you can exit the photo app.

But with the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE you have to klick on a button to open the intent, take the image klick OK, klick again on the button to open the intent...

Is it possible, to open an IMAGE_CAPTURE intent take as many photos as you like and return to the activity and work with these images?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many libraries for that.

Just try this [Whatsapp like photo picker](https://github.com/Jitesh1720/PixImagePicker)

Checkout the sample and library

```
Pix.start(Context,                    //Activity or Fragment Instance
                    RequestCode,                //Request code for activity results
                    NumberOfImagesToSelect);    //Number of images to restict selection count
```

You will get the result in onActivityResult

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == RequestCode) {
                    ArrayList<String> returnValue = data.getStringArrayListExtra(Pix.IMAGE_RESULTS);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't need a photo picker. I need to take photos with the default camera intent but I need to take more than one photo.

Comment: Maybe there is a library that does just what I need, but I seem to be much too silly to find it